# (JDBC) SQL Server connection string: login failed for user ' '

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string

> jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;Data Source=(local); Initial
>   Catalog=MarketDataDB; User Id=andrew;
>   Password=mypassword;

Above is the connection string I am using to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 Express database using JDBC, but this error is produced:

**Login failed for user ' '**

Any ideas?

I can successfully connect to the database from within SQL Server Management Studio using the specified username and password. I am using *SQL Server authentication*

Answer (score 0):

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\[InstanceName???]:1433;Data Source=(local); InitialCatalog=MarketDataDB; 
User Id=andrew; Password=mypassword;
```

You are missing Instance name in you string try this

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

Comment: It's a local database, what would the instance name be?

Comment: LocalHost is the location name where your server is located, Instance name is what you use when connection to a server, One server can have many instances of Sql server if you have only one Instance installed than it will be the default instance name it is LocalHost\MSSQLSERVER

Comment: when you connect to this sql server using SSMS you must me using something like Localhost\MSSQLSERVER or .\MSSQLSERVER whatever you type in after the back slash to connect to this instance is your instance name.

Comment: is this is what you use when connecting to SSMS ??

Comment: Can you connect to your server using SSMS and passing Server name as  localhost\SQLEXPRESS  ???

Comment: Experiencing some odd issues when I tried logging in specifying the instance name. The database is set up to accept both windows authentication and SQL server authentication but mysteriously the sql server logon is now failing and the database no longer exists when logging in via windows authentication. Will update soon but it seems there might be another issue.

Comment: Restarted my computer, and for some reason my database no longer exists when logging in through windows authentication and my SQL server user fails to login. The database wasn't deleted... no idea what happened to it.

Comment: This is very strange indeed, Trying to connect to a data can never result in deletion of that database, if really the database has been deleted restarting pc wont bring it back, I hope you have a backup for that database :) do you???

Comment: An instance name is not required, and if you specify a port, the instance name is even ignored.

Answer (score 0):

1433 is the default port for SQL Server, not for SQLExpress. By default, SQLExpress uses a dynamically assigned port number. You can check this or change this using the Configuration Manager applet.

I am sure you realize that a default installation of SQLExpress does not enable TCP/IP at all. Applications can connect to SQLExpress using the Shared Memory protocol (only from the same machine, of course). To use TCP/IP you must enable it in the Configuration Manager. After enabling TCP/IP you must stop and restart SQLExpress for the new setting to take effect.