# Login failed for user, using JDBC in Java to connect to MS SQL Server 2017

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, authorization, ssms

When trying to connect to MS SQL Server 2017 (developer) using the JDBC driver inside a Java (JDK 1.8.x) REST application I keep getting the error:

> Login failed for user 'USER_TEST'.
>   ClientConnectionId:3e6efb24-58cf-4854-a3d7-aa27cd596f20

I created the user in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and can verify it exists. This is how it was created:

```
USE SQLDB

CREATE ROLE TEST
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON SCHEMA :: [dbo] TO TEST
CREATE LOGIN TEST_LOGIN WITH PASSWORD = 'abc'
CREATE USER USER_TEST FROM LOGIN TEST_LOGIN
ALTER ROLE TEST ADD MEMBER USER_TEST
```

To verify I can login using these credentials:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'USER_TEST'
REVERT
```

After that I try to connect with this connection string:

```
String connectionUrl =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;"
                        + "database=SQLDB;"
                        + "user=USER_TEST;"
                        + "password=abc;"
                        + "encrypt=false;"
                        + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
                        + "loginTimeout=30;";
```

Following is a screen from SSMS showing the configuration for the user:
[image]

The security settings for the server are:
[image]

I tried changing my connection string as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181213/jdbc-sql-server-connection-string-login-failed-for-user) post but that had no effect so I changed it back. I tried changing it to:

```
String connectionUrl =
                "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\MSSQLSERVER:1433;"
                        + "database=SQLDB;"
                        + "user=USER_TEST;"
                        + "password=abc;"
                        + "encrypt=false;"
                        + "trustServerCertificate=false;"
                        + "loginTimeout=30;";
```

If you need any more information feel free to ask.

Comment: It still results in the same error.

Comment: @JimGarrison That needs to be a single backslash, so it's already correctly escaped. In addition, given a port is specified, the instance name will be ignored entirely.

Comment: You need to login with `test_login`, not with `user_test`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel looks like you are correct. I feel pretty dumb right now for missing that. Thanks.